# Dragging And Swapping tab Android

Tags: android, tabs, drag-and-drop

Hello Guys I am trying to implement tab dragging in one of my project that is supposed to run on **android 2.2** or higher  which is similar to Google chromium Desktop browser in dragging and swapping .

I have thought the following way to implement it which are as follow and

1. using the given logic http://jqfaq.com/how-to-drag-and-drop-replace-the-position/ with **Linear Layout** as vertical orientation and adding and removing element with gesture and animation
2. using Custom ViewPager and Fragments to achieve the same
3. Extending FrameLayout and adding and removing tab dynamically and when user press and start dragging then shuffle all the tab .. but this way in need to destroy and create all  the visible tab again to give the same effects  , with this way might work but mine progress and activity work will has to be recreated
4. Using Activity Group as Drag and Drop with view start from api level 11

i hope you guys got my problem and come up with suggestion and if have some ready made sample and best way to it